# Find the missing letter in a well known sequence beginning with 80

Tags: knowledge, sequence

Here is a well known sequence of 118 items, which begins with 80.

Please find the missing letter. (marked by a ?)

> 39, 44, 68, 115, 10, 16, 23, 92, 1, 68, 85, 38, 95, 15, 22, 68, 92, ?,
> 16, 85, 86, 92, 11, 16, 44, 92, 7, 52, 63, 93

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you

> convert the numbers to the corresponding periodic table abbreviations

you get:

> `YRuErMcNeSVUHErAtSrAmPTiErU?NaSRuUNTeEuNp`

As hinted by "starting with 80",

> the 80th element is Mercury, so these are the planets. If we split the string up as follows...
>
>  `YRuErMc NeSVU HErAt SrAm PTiErU? NaSRuU NTeEuNp`
>
>  ...these spell out anagrams of the planets (except SATURN has an extra U and is missing a T - I believe that to be an error in the puzzle). So the missing letter is the **J** in Jupiter.

Comment: Yep! I skipped S entirely somehow. Will add in for posterity.